# Getting low accuracy when compiling multiple models one after another in the same program

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I tried executing those models singularly by putting the other sections in the comments, but as soon as I start uncommenting the lines and running the whole code together, it stops giving good results.

Note: I am only getting low accuracy results in the models using CNNs. I don't know why. I suspect maybe I need to import the data each time but that doesn't make any sense.

Note: When I run the same code on Google Colab, I get good results. The platform where I am not getting good results is PuTTy using which I have to submit this code.

Interestingly, I am only facing problems with the second model (convolution before l2 regularization). Have I done anything wrong when defining that model?

```
IMG_SIZE=28
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import extract_images, extract_labels
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def convert(x):
    y=numpy.zeros([len(x),10])
    z=numpy.eye(10)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y[i]=(z[(x[i])])
    return y


with open('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'rb') as f:
    train_images = extract_images(f)
with open('train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'rb') as f:
    train_labels = extract_labels(f)

with open('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'rb') as f:
    test_images = extract_images(f)
with open('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'rb') as f:
    test_labels = extract_labels(f)


train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

#"""
print("\n\n\n############# USING REGULARIZATIONS #############")

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=train_images[0].shape),
            keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001), bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
            keras.layers.Dense(500,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001), bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
            keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])
l2_history=model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=3,validation_split=0.13)
loss,accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images,test_labels, verbose=2)
print('\n\n\nTest accuracy with l2 regularization:',accuracy)
#"""
#"""
print("\n\n\n############# USING CONVOLUTION BEFORE REGULARIZATIONS #############")
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)),
            keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            keras.layers.Flatten(),
            keras.layers.Dense(500,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001), bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
            keras.layers.Dense(500,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001), bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
            keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])
train_images_new = train_images.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)
test_images_new = test_images.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)
l2_conv_history=model.fit(train_images_new, train_labels, epochs=3,validation_split=0.13)
loss,accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images_new,test_labels, verbose=2)
print('\n\n\nTest accuracy with convolution before l2 regularization:',accuracy)
#"""
#"""
print("\n\n\n############# USING DROPOUT #############")

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=train_images[0].shape),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
            keras.layers.Dense(500,activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
            keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])
dropout_history=model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=3,validation_split=0.13)
loss,accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images,test_labels, verbose=2)
print('\n\n\nTest accuracy with l2 regularization:',accuracy)
#"""
#"""
print("\n\n\n############# USING CONVOLUTION BEFORE DROPOUT #############")

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)),
            keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
            keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            keras.layers.Flatten(),
            keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
            keras.layers.Dense(500,activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
            keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])
train_images_new = train_images.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)
test_images_new = test_images.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)
dropout_conv_history=model.fit(train_images_new, train_labels, epochs=3,validation_split=0.13)
loss,accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images_new,test_labels, verbose=2)
print('\n\n\nTest accuracy with convolution before dropout:',accuracy)
#"""
#"""
plt.figure(figsize=(50,20))
plt.subplot(2,4,1)
plt.plot(l2_history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(l2_history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('accuracy vs epoch (with l2 regularization)')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(2,4,2)
plt.plot(dropout_history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(dropout_history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('accuracy vs epoch (with dropout)')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(2,4,3)
plt.plot(l2_history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(l2_history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('classification error vs epoch (with l2 regularization)')
plt.ylabel('classification error')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(2,4,4)
plt.plot(dropout_history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(dropout_history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('classification error vs epoch (with dropout)')
plt.ylabel('classification error')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(2,4,5)
plt.plot(l2_conv_history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(l2_conv_history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('accuracy vs epoch (with convolution before l2 regularization)')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(2,4,6)
plt.plot(dropout_conv_history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(dropout_conv_history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('accuracy vs epoch (with convolution before dropout)')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(2,4,7)
plt.plot(l2_conv_history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(l2_conv_history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('classification error vs epoch (with convolution before l2 regularization)')
plt.ylabel('classification error')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(2,4,8)
plt.plot(dropout_conv_history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(dropout_conv_history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('classification error vs epoch (with convolution before dropout)')
plt.ylabel('classification error')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
#plt.savefig("A04mpm514Q2.png")
plt.clf()
#"""
```

Here's the concerned output

```
############# USING CONVOLUTION BEFORE REGULARIZATIONS #############
Train on 52200 samples, validate on 7800 samples
Epoch 1/3
52200/52200 [==============================]52200/52200 [==============================] - 272s 5ms/step - loss: 9.2077 - acc: 0.2311 - val_loss: 15.0802 - val_acc: 0.1004

Epoch 2/3
52200/52200 [==============================]52200/52200 [==============================] - 273s 5ms/step - loss: 15.1176 - acc: 0.0969 - val_loss: 15.0435 - val_acc: 0.1004

Epoch 3/3
52200/52200 [==============================]52200/52200 [==============================] - 269s 5ms/step - loss: 15.0821 - acc: 0.0969 - val_loss: 15.0092 - val_acc: 0.1004

Test accuracy with convolution before l2 regularization: 0.0982
```

And here's the ouput when the same code is run on Google Colab

```
############# USING CONVOLUTION BEFORE REGULARIZATIONS #############
Train on 52200 samples, validate on 7800 samples
Epoch 1/3
52200/52200 [==============================] - 6s 111us/sample - loss: 1.9528 - acc: 0.5949 - val_loss: 1.2696 - val_acc: 0.7654
Epoch 2/3
52200/52200 [==============================] - 6s 113us/sample - loss: 0.8080 - acc: 0.9250 - val_loss: 0.7072 - val_acc: 0.9515
Epoch 3/3
52200/52200 [==============================] - 6s 110us/sample - loss: 0.6900 - acc: 0.9518 - val_loss: 0.6427 - val_acc: 0.9621
10000/10000 - 1s - loss: 0.6343 - acc: 0.9631



Test accuracy with convolution before l2 regularization: 0.9631
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing the session between runs, so there will be junk floating around in the kernel which is leading to poor results. Between each model you should be [resetting Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session):

```py
<some model code>
model.fit()

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

<more model code>
model.fit()
```

Comment: I thought so but I am not getting why it is only affecting the models having convolutional layers in it. For instance, I get good results in the third model (with dropout).

Comment: It may be a very complicated answer based on what is left floating around in the kernel. Did clearing your session fix the issue?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I am afraid that it will be resolved but I am not using that solution because I have submitted assignments previously without clearing sessions where I was getting expected results as it is.

Comment: BTW, clearing the session doesn't work either. @pciunkiewicz

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out the exact reason. However, I tried to change the order in which the models were trained (I put the ones using CNNs before the other two) and it worked for me.
Please comment if anyone figures out the problem.
Thank you.